# How to match over self in an enum?

Tags: enums, pattern-matching, rust

I have an enum:

```
enum Expr {
    Lit(u32),
    Var(Id),
    Ass(Id, u32),
    Add(u32, u32),
    Sub(u32, u32),
    Mul(u32, u32),
}
```

I'm trying to implement a method:

```
impl Expr {
    fn eval(&self, env: &mut Env) -> Result<u32, String> {
        use Expr::*;

        match *self {
            Lit(l) => Ok(l),
            Var(id) => env.lookup(&id).ok_or_else(|| format!("undefined var {:?}", id)),
            Ass(id, v) => {
                env.assign(id, v);
                Ok(v)
            }
            Add(f, s) => Ok(f + s),
            Sub(f, s) => Ok(f - s),
            Mul(f, s) => Ok(f * s),
        }
    }
}
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:25:15
   |
25 |         match *self {
   |               ^^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
26 |             Lit(l) => Ok(l),
27 |             Var(id) => env.lookup(&id).ok_or_else(|| format!("undefined var {:?}", id)),
   |                 -- hint: to prevent move, use `ref id` or `ref mut id`
28 |             Ass(id, v) => {
   |                 -- ...and here (use `ref id` or `ref mut id`)
```

Without the star, I'm also getting an error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:25:17
   |
25 |                 Lit(l) => Ok(l),
   |                 ^^^^^^ expected &Expr, found enum `Expr`
   |
   = note: expected type `&Expr`
   = note:    found type `Expr`
```

I think I understand the first error: I'm trying to do more than I'm allowed with the (immutable) borrowed `self`, but I'm not really sure about the second error. I have no idea how to do this properly.

Comment: You could also make `Expr` copyable. Or consume it during evaluation if you don't need it again after evaluation anyway.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For the first question, you need to use the `ref` keyword, as said by @Adrian:

```
impl Expr {
    fn eval(&self, env: &mut Env) -> Result<u32, String> {
        use Expr::*;

        match *self {
            Lit(l) => Ok(l),
            Var(ref id) => env.lookup(id).ok_or_else(|| format!("undefined var {:?}", id)),
            Ass(ref id, v) => {
                env.assign(id.clone(), v);
                Ok(v)
            }
            Add(f, s) => Ok(f + s),
            Sub(f, s) => Ok(f - s),
            Mul(f, s) => Ok(f * s),
        }
    }
}
```

Using `ref` prevents the pattern matching from taking ownership of `id`. As you mention, you are not allowed to take the value of `id` out of the `Expr` because you only have an immutable reference. `v`, `f`, and `s` don't have this problem because they are `u32`, which implements [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html). Instead of taking the value out, they are copied, leaving the original in place.

I don't know what the `Env` or `Id` type are, or the definitions of `lookup` and `assign`, so perhaps some `clone()` calls are not necessary.

For your second question, this is because `self` is of type `&Expr`, so you need to include `&` in the patterns:

```
impl Expr {
    fn eval(&self, env: &mut Env) -> Result<u32, String> {
        use Expr::*;

        match self {
            &Lit(l) => Ok(l),
            &Var(ref id) => env.lookup(id).ok_or_else(|| format!("undefined var {:?}", id)),
            &Ass(ref id, v) => {
                env.assign(id.clone(), v);
                Ok(v)
            }
            &Add(f, s) => Ok(f + s),
            &Sub(f, s) => Ok(f - s),
            &Mul(f, s) => Ok(f * s),
        }
    }
}
```

Both forms of matching are equivalent, but `*self` is more idiomatic and requires less typing :)

Comment: Looks like something changed in Rust language, because as of 2021 the asterisk is not required, first variant with 'match self' works.

Comment: Yeah, this is called match ergonomics, but I don't recommend using this because it can provide confusing error messages.