# Implementing fmt::Display for enum - cannot move out of borrowed content

Tags: rust

I tried implementing `fmt::Display` for an `enum`, though I had a hard time understanding references:

```
use std::fmt;

enum Car {
    BMW,
    Ford,
    TopSpeed(i32),
    Specs { weight: i32, name: String },
}

impl fmt::Display for Car {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match self {
            &Car::BMW => write!(f, "[Car] BMW"),
            &Car::Ford => write!(f, "[Car] Ford"),
            &Car::TopSpeed(i) => write!(f, "[Car] TopSpeed={}", i),
            &Car::Specs { weight, name } => write!(f, "[Car] Weight={}, Name={}", weight, name),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("This is a {}", Car::BMW);
    println!("This is a {}", Car::Ford);
    println!("This is a {}", Car::TopSpeed(200));
    println!("This is a {}",
             Car::Specs {
                 weight: 2000,
                 name: "Clio".to_owned(),
             });
}
```

It gets an error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:16:13
   |
16 |             &Car::Specs { weight, name } => write!(f, "[Car] Weight={}, Name={}", weight, name),
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^----^^
   |             |                     |
   |             |                     hint: to prevent move, use `ref name` or `ref mut name`
   |             cannot move out of borrowed content
```

If I change to `ref name` as the compiler suggests:

```
&Car::Specs { weight, ref name } => write!(f, "[Car] Weight={}, Name={}", weight, name),
```

It works. Why do I need to mark `name` as `ref`?

Comment: Unrelated to your core issue, that's not really a proper use of an `enum`. It may just be an artifact of playing around or of a minimized example, but "top speed" and "BMW" don't seem like exclusive choices.

Comment: Yeah I know it isn't really a good use, I just tried doing something like what is on http://rustbyexample.com/custom_types/enum.html and experimented a bit.

Comment: I'm sorry that the Rust by Example enum looks like that, and I'm very happy to hear that you know that's not a good example of how to use an enum!

Comment: @Shepmaster I think I sort of understand it now. The String is owned and the only way I can access it is by making a reference to it right? I didn't know that since i'm on chapter 3 of Rust by Example and borrowing is on chapter 13...

Comment: @Shepmaster I think this one solved it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33925232/how-to-match-over-self-in-an-enum.

Comment: Great! I've deleted my meta comments (and I'll delete this one soon too) but left other comments that might be useful to future people. Sorry to be such a pain, but we want to work hard to make [tag:rust] a great resource for everyone coming after, and that means sometimes being a bit ogreish!