# How do I make use of the `self` data in a method implemented on an enum?

Tags: enums, rust

I am working through the docs on enums and I'm at implementing a method on an enum.  How do I make use of the `self` info passed into the method?

```
fn main() {
    enum Message {
        Quit,
        Move { x: i32, y: i32 },
        Write(String),
        ChangeColor(i32, i32, i32),
    }

    impl Message {
        fn call(&self) {
            //Want to make use of 'self'
        }
    }

    let m = Message::Write(String::from("hello"));
    m.call();
}
```

To get something to print I have to:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Message {
    Quit,
    Move { x: i32, y: i32 },
    Write(String),
    ChangeColor(i32, i32, i32),
}

impl Message {
    fn call(&self) {
        println!("{:?}", self);
    }
}
```

If I try to make use of `self` or get only the 'Hello' string I get a:

```
impl Message {
    fn call(&self) {
        println!("{}", self::Write);
    }
}
```

```
error[E0425]: cannot find value `Write` in module `self`
--> src/main.rs:14:28
   |
14 |       println!("{}", self::Write);
   |                            ^^^^^ not found in `self`
```

Comment: Does [How to match over self in an enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33925232/155423) answer your question? [Why can't `Self` be used to refer to an enum's variant in a method body?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46396796/155423) is related.

Comment: Bear in mind that a method can be called on an instance of an `enum` regardless of which variant it is - `self` could be `Quit`, `Move`, `Write` *or* `ChangeColor`. If you want to access what's inside a `Message::Write`, you first need to make sure that `self` actually *is* a `Message::Write`. The first code example Shepmaster linked shows one way to do this.

Comment: Thank you. Late here. I'll take a look at this tomorrow.